# In the Delphi IDE is there are a keyboard shortcut to use the surround commands

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts

If I highlight some text in the Delphi IDE, I can right click, Surround, and select ifb (for `if` with `begin`).  I was wondering if there was a keyboard short cut that works with these similar to CTRL+J does with completion type templates?

Comment: A quick Google search for *Delphi keyboard shortcuts* turns up https://shortcutworld.com/Delphi/win/Delphi_10_Shortcuts which says Ctrl+/ will do what you're asking.

Comment: @KenWhite You are forgetting that keyboard shortcuts depend on [Editor Options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Editor_Options) or more specifically on `Editor SpeedSetting` with which you can set one of several keybinding presets.

Comment: @SilverWarior: I didn't forget anything. :-) I posted a comment and not an answer for that very reason.

Comment: @KenWhite Ctrl+/ is comment line.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see what Keyboard shortcuts are used for executing of certain quick actions in code editor I recommend against web search as it was proposed by @KenWhite but instead checking Delphi documentation on specific `Editor SpeedSetting` that your have set in Delphi [Editor Options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Editor_Options) as this setting controls what keyboard shortcuts are used for executing of which quick actions.

And yes you can see detailed information for each `Editor SpeedSetting` preset. For instance you can find detailed information about keyboard shortcuts for [Default keymapping](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Default_Keyboard_Shortcuts) here.

Also bear in mind that there were some changes between different Delphi versions so make sure you are checking the documentation for Delphi version you are currently using.